# How can I get an image to appear behind a nav bar link when I hover over it?

Tags: html, css

I've created a nav bar at the top of my page, with links. I've made each link turn green when you hover over it, but I also wanted to have an image fade in behind. I'm really new to this and have read the tutorials I can find but nothing seems to be going right - any advice would be really appreciated!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f74178;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
  margin: 5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.navbar a img {
  display: none;
}

a:hover img {
  display: block;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #b7fa00;
}

#header-logo {
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

body {
  cursor: crosshair
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#customs" img src="Cloud.png">customs</a>
      <a href="#apparel">apparel</a>
      <a href="#about">about</a>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" width="15%">
      <a href="#news">news</a>
      <a href="#ethics">ethics</a>
      <a href="#contact">contact</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

It's the 'cloud.png' that I am wanting popping up behind each nav bar link. I've been trying to make it work just for the customs one but will be adding to all links once I've found the solution. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f74178;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  align-content: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: none;
  margin: 5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
   padding: 10px;
}

.navbar a img {
  display: none;
   position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
   max-width: 120px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, max-width 0.5s;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover .overlay-img {
display: block;
  opacity: 0.5; /* Adjust the opacity as desired */
  max-width: 130px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: #b7fa00;
}


#header-logo {
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

body {
  cursor: crosshair
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
       <a href="#">
        <img src="https://unsplash.imgix.net/44/9s1lvXLlSbCX5l3ZaYWP_hdr-1.jpg" class="overlay-img">
        <span>Home page</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#apparel">apparel</a>
      <a href="#about">about</a>
      <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" width="15%">
      <a href="#news">news</a>
      <a href="#ethics">ethics</a>
      <a href="#contact">contact</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

It looks like there are a few adjustments needed in your HTML and CSS to achieve the desired effect.

I hope your problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: wow that's great, works absolutely perfectly! thank you so much :)